# AFNetworking 2.0 - mutable json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

My code currently looks like this

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLForSend];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                     initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
     [BoxJsonDataHelper gotNewJson:responseObject];
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
 }];

[operation start];
```

But when trying to edit dictionaries in object received, I get an error about using methods that belongs to a mutable dictionary rather than a dictionary.
How do I make AFNetworking use nested mutable objects instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get mutable dictionaries from AFNetworking and AFJSONRequestOperation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409760/how-do-you-get-mutable-dictionaries-from-afnetworking-and-afjsonrequestoperation)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You tell the [`AFJSONResponseSerializer`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFJSONResponseSerializer.html#//api/name/serializerWithReadingOptions%3a) that it needs to return mutable containers:

```
operation.responseSerializer = 
  [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers]
```

It is all very well documented: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/

Comment: Thank, I understood wrong from the documentation that it is suppose to be the default.

Comment: BTW this option optimizes a bit memory handling, because it doesn't copy mutable container into immutable one. And to return also mutable leaves: manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves];